# Do I need to have my account unlocked for a mining pool

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, wallets, mining-pools

I have a mining pool and I'm using geth. Do i need to keep my pool wallet unlocked in geth in order for the pool to work? Includes unlocking blocks and sending payments to miners on the pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the pool software.

You only need to have an unlocked wallet in order to sign transactions; technically, you could get away with unlocking only for payouts. For security purposes, you could generate the payout transaction and sign it on an air-gapped computer. Thus, you never need to have a computer with an unlocked wallet connected to the Internet.